# How Insert datetime from datagridview to database? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, function, datetime, datagridview, insert

i want Insert datetime from datagridview to database.But i'm don't save required.

**Ex.**

```
Datagridview
DAte
2012-11-20 16:36:39

when i'm save to datagridview to datebase
DAte
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

I want save 2012-11-20 16:36:39 to dataasbe but it's don't result.

**Show Datagridview**

```
    Dim sqlSentMaterial As String = ""
    Dim DT_SentMaterial As New DataTable

    sqlSentMaterial = "SELECT rc.No,rc.ReceiveDate as RCReceiveDate,rc.CreateBy as RCReceiveBy,rc.CreateDate,rc.ReceiveNote "
    sqlSentMaterial &= "FROM RClother rc "
    sqlSentMaterial &= "Where rc.No ='" & Search & "'"
    DT_SentMaterial = FShowData(sqlSentMaterial)

   For i As Integer = 0 To DT_SentMaterial.Rows.Count - 1
        If DT_SentMaterial.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            Dim item As New DataGridViewRow
            item.CreateCells(DgvSentMaterial)
            With item
                .Cells(1).Value = TxtBarcode.Text 
                If DT_SentMaterial.Rows(0).Item("RCReceiveDate") Is DBNull.Value Then
                    .Cells(2).Value = ""
                Else
                    .Cells(2).Value = CDate(DT_SentMaterial.Rows(0).Item("RCReceiveDate")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                End If
            End With
            DgvSentMaterial.Rows.Add(item)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

**Form save datagridview to database**

```
Private Sub BtnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
Dim sentMat As Integer

sentMat = FInsertSentMatClother(CInt(DgvSentMaterial.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value), CDate(DgvSentMaterial.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value))
End Sub
```

**Function Insert To Database**

```
Public Function FInsert_iPOSentMatClother(ByVal BarCode As Integer, ByVal RCReceiveDate As Date)

        Dim Tr As SqlTransaction
        Dim sqlCom As New SqlCommand

        Dim sqlInsert As String
        Dim ReturnValue As Integer
        Dim GetDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now

        Try
            Tr = Conn.BeginTransaction
            sqlCom.Connection = Conn


            sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO SentMatClother "
            sqlInsert &= "(BarCode,ReceiveDate) "
            sqlInsert &= "VALUES('" & BarCode & "','" & RCReceiveDate & "')"

            sqlCom.Transaction = Tr
            sqlCom.CommandText = sqlInsert
            sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            ReturnValue = CInt(sqlCom.ExecuteScalar) 'CInt(sqlCom.ExecuteScalar)
            If ReturnValue = 0 Then
                Tr.Commit()
            Else
                Tr.Rollback()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            If Not sqlCom Is Nothing Then
                sqlCom.Dispose()
            End If
            sqlCom = Nothing
        End Try
        Return ReturnValue

    End Function
```

**Thanks you for you time. :)**

Comment: Use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) so that you don't have to format it into a string, just to then have SQL convert it back into a `DateTime`. Also, it looks suspiciously like you're sharing a single connection object around - it's usually far better to have a local connection object that you open, use, then close (or Dispose, possibly via a `Using` statement). Behind the scenes, connection pooling should keep the number of actual connections used to a sensible number.

Answer (score 0):

in your `Function insert to database` just format Date value in string as you want

```
sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO SentMatClother "
sqlInsert &= "(BarCode,ReceiveDate) "
sqlInsert &= "VALUES('" & BarCode & "','" & RCReceiveDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & "')"
```

or and on my opinion is a better practice using a parameters:

```
sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO SentMatClother (BarCode,ReceiveDate) VALUES (@barCode, @receiveDate)"

//then add parameters to your sqlCommand

sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barCode", BarCode)
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barCode", RCReceiveDate)
```